# I don't understand why this is an XSS warning Rails 4. Unsafe model attribute in link_to href

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a show view with this code:

```
 %ul.pager
   %li.pull-left{ class: ('disabled' if collection_of_all_topics.index(@topic).zero?) }
     = link_to t('.previous_topic_html'), previous_topic(collection_of_all_topics, @topic)
   %li.pull-right{ class: ('disabled' if collection_of_all_topics.index(@topic).zero?) }
     = link_to t('.next_topic_html'), next_topic(collection_of_all_topics, @topic)
```

When I try to execute a `brakeman -q` command I receive these two warnings:

```
     Medium     | topics/show (TopicsController#show) | Cross Site Scripting | Unsafe model attribute in link_to href near line 29: link_to(t(".previous_topic_html"), previous_topi>>
| Medium     | topics/show (TopicsController#show) | Cross Site Scripting | Unsafe model attribute in link_to href near line 31: link_to(t(".next_topic_html"), next_topic(+Topic>>
```

For the path parameter of the link_to method I have a set of logic that calculates the next and previous topic located in my topic_helper.rb file:

```
 module TopicsHelper
  def next_topic?(collection_of_all_topics, topic)
    !(topic == collection_of_all_topics.last)
  end

  def next_topic(collection_of_all_topics, topic)
    return '' unless next_topic?(collection_of_all_topics, topic)
    topic_path(collection_of_all_topics[(collection_of_all_topics.index(topic) + 1)])
  end

  def previous_topic(collection_of_all_topics, topic)
    topic_path(collection_of_all_topics[(collection_of_all_topics.index(topic) - 1)])
  end
end
```

I've done some reading on the Rails guides with XSS under the security section but I still don't understand what the problem is here, or more importantly how to fix it. I've tried these methods to fix the error:

```
 = h(link_to t('.previous_topic_html'), previous_topic(collection_of_all_topics, @topic))

 = sanitize(link_to t('.previous_topic_html'), previous_topic(collection_of_all_topics, @topic))

 = link_to t('.previous_topic_html'), sanitize(previous_topic(collection_of_all_topics, @topic))

 = link_to t('.previous_topic_html'), h(previous_topic(collection_of_all_topics, @topic))
```

These implementations still result in the warning. Why is this a warning and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brakeman is complaining because you are accessing attributes of `@topic` in the view. The TopicsHelper might be triggering it? Check out their explanation [here](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/cross_site_scripting/). IMO, Brakeman is a bit too sensitive on this issue. If you're really concerned, sanitize should do the trick. The danger here is that an end user could manipulate the @topic id in the link and access other Topics. Is that an issue for you?

See this issue on Brakeman's [github issues](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/683).

See also this [issue](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/597).

TLDR; this is PROBABLY a false positive and should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Chase. Can you provide an example with the sanitize method? I've already tried to use sanitize as shown in the code at the bottom of my question. I still get the warning. Also, Rails uses link_to paths such as link_to topic_path(@topic) all the time. Essentially my code does the same. I'm not sure why it would raise an error.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I think this warning is safe to ignore. I think the warning is related to this issue https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/683

Comment: I added two issues and a recommendation to my answer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the help Chase. It seemed those issues is what was happening for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm always excited to see other Rails folks think about security.

Comment: Even better, generate an HTML or JSON report and it will link you to http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/link_to_href/ In this case you can use `--url-safe-methods` to whitelist your methods. Unfortunately Rails does not provide a "sanitize"-like method to make this safe.

Comment: I like the above response